# How did the Millennium Falcon lose its second rectangular dish?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon, galaxys-edge

The Millennium Falcon loses its dish (or "rectenna") many times throughout the films:

- In *Solo*, Lando's perpendicular dish gets scraped off during the Kessel run.
- In *Return of the Jedi*, the round dish gets scraped off during the Battle of Endor.
- In *The Last Jedi*, the rectangular dish gets scraped off during the Battle of Crait.

But in Galaxy's Edge,  which takes place between *The Last Jedi* and *The Rise of Skywalker*,  the Falcon seems to have another rectangular dish:

[image: Image of the Millennium Falcon at Galaxy's Edge]

This is seen also in *Tales from the Galaxy's Edge*, which also takes place after TLJ:

[image: Screenshot of the Millennium Falcon on Batuu in Tales from the Galaxy's Edge]

Is there a canon source that says when and why this dish was replaced with the round one seen in *The Rise of Skywalker*?

Comment: Galaxy's Edge is very firmly non-canon. Not even Legends

Comment: @Valorum How do you figure? If nothing else, the [_Traveler's Guide to Batuu_](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Traveler%27s_Guide_to_Batuu) is canon and includes images of a rectangular-dished Falcon.

Comment: just because the rides contain elements from within the canon (such as the Millennium Falcon and strormtroopers) does not make them canon.

Comment: @Valorum From a Lucasfilm exec: "'[The events at Galaxy’s Edge] are meant to be canonical,' Martin explained. 'I wouldn’t say that you as an individual, dressed in Earth clothes, are now part of actual canon, but the storytelling is meant to be really part of Star Wars, down to its place on the timeline. I can’t get into it, but I know the specific day that the events of this park take place.'" —[Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/star-wars/2019/5/30/18645775/star-wars-land-disneyland-story-canon-galaxys-edge)

Comment: There are obvious elements of the park that are concessions to its existence in the real world (and literal concessions, in the case of [Coca-Cola](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Coca-Cola)) but Disney has been consistent in presenting its locations, characters, scripted events, etc. as canonical material. I'm just curious whether minor details like the radar dish are among them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Matt Martin of the Lucasfilm Story Group, the square dish you see on the Falcon at Disneyland was a cheap addition by Hondo Ohnaka. No special explanation is required as to how it lost it, other than that it presumably thrown away and replaced with one that was less crappy.

> **Q.** *So did Falcon lose rectangle dish on Crait, replace with another rectangle, lose that one again from so many random pilots working for Hondo, and then finally go back to a circle one?*
>
> **MM:** *Yeah. Hondo made a few modifications, including putting on a new cheap dish.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1209525503192731648)</sup></sub>

and

> **MM:** *Yes to both. **Hondo replaced the dish** (and made some other adjustments to the ship including adding two more seats and a harpoon). Poe got a new X-wing and did it up with his classic livery.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1206357500544475136)</sup></sub>